# A macro to extract characters of its input text and generate a code using them

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there any macro that can get a text as input like "abc" and by text I literally mean text like the one mentioned not an array or anything else, then extract characters of that text and generate a selective piece of code like ones below at compile time:

***first example of a piece of code :***

```
Func1(a);
Func2(b);
Func3(c);
```

***second example of a piece of code:***

```
{'a','b','c'}
```

Comment: Unlikely. If you want code generation, you might want to write a script to generate this code and incorporate it into the build process.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you ideally want a macro that you can invoke as `MY_MACRO("abc");`?  I think the answer is no.

Comment: @delnan_could you give an explanation on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with a string "abc", but you can do it with (a,b,c). Look at boost preprocessor metaprogramming library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html.